# Using ffmpeg audio filter loop instead of stream_loop as stream_loop adds a delay

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I want to loop an audio file infinitely. The `-stream_loop -1` option adds a small pause  / jerk between the loops, as also mentioned in [this question with no solution](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/why-does-ffmpegs-stream-loop-option-add-a-pause).
The same question mentions that filter loop works fine without delay. But I am unable to get the filter loop to work. The below code along with rest of the command:

```
 -filter_complex "[1:a]aloop=loop=-1"
```

gives a warning:

```
[Parsed_aloop_0 @ 0x55d83e516b80] Number of samples to loop is not set!
```

What is the correct way to loop an audio endlessly using filter loop? I am trying to merge a video and audio, having them both independently loop infinitely. I have got that part to work using `-stream_loop -1` but it has a minor delay between loops as I mentioned. I am looking for a solution using either `filter_complex` or any other way if possible. Thanks!

Note, I have also noticed that `ffplay -loop 0`  plays the loop smoothly without adding this pause.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/vooezk/stream_loop_creates_gap_in_audio/)! Using `wav` file as input instead of `mp3` works.

Also in my trials, I found that even `aac` files suffer from this delay, somehow, `wav` files do not!